# Javascript map use HTMLElement as key

Tags: javascript, dictionary

As title suggests,  I'm using HTMLElement as key to javascript's map container

consider the following example

```
let map =  new Map(), 
    nodeA = document.createElement("b"), 
    nodeB = document.createElement("b");
map[nodeA] = 5;
console.log(map[nodeB]); // prints 5
```

now clearly nodeA.isSameNode(nodeB) would give you false.

After playing around it for a bit, I found that Map would treat elements with the same tag name as being "equal", doesn't matter if they are actually the same node.

Is there a way to get around this behavior? i.e. I would want different nodes being treated as different keys.

**edit** thanks MarcelD for pointing out. I meant to say map[nodeB] as fixed, and thanks to the answers. Stupid mistake

Comment: are u sure that ur example describes ur problem? cause in this case console.log(nodeB) won't print 5 ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't use [`Map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) as intended.

Instead of `map[nodeA] = 5` you need to write `map.set(nodeA, 5)`.
Otherwise you simply add a new property with string key `"[object HTMLElement]"` and value `5`.

```js
let nodeA = document.createElement("b");
let nodeB = document.createElement("b");

let map = new Map();
map.set(nodeA, 5);
map.set(nodeB, 1);

console.log(map.get(nodeA)); // 5
console.log(map.get(nodeB)); // 1
```

Answer (score 0):

@le_m is right. So you should fix that. But to address your question:

Map has key, value pairs. And although with map you can put in anything you want, it's still a key. As in: An unique identifier. If you want different objects, you need different keys.

For you to solve the problem, I would check if the key already exists first, if it does add a number or something to make it unque (e.a. ”_1") and check if that exists! Repeat until it's unique.

To read it back, just check if the last part has an underscore and number value.